# Error message here end Kernel Panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, initramfs, kernel-panic

My OS crashed while I was using normally the navigator and a text editor, so I've decided to force the shutdown manually, when the screen turned on and it was loading the OS it appeared that busybox screen where I am supposed to type something in initramfs, so I have typed:

`<initramfs> fsck /dev/sda2/`

And I typed yes in all questions during this process,

Now I am facing this screen each time when I turn on the PC:

[image]

How could I proceed on it?? I have searched in whole net any answer that could help me out but it looks like that there are no solutions for it. My Ubuntu version is the Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

I have tried to run these commands below from this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/910218/sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory-not-able-to-boot-ubuntu-desktop suggested by TopHat about update my kernel but when I did `sudo mount -a` I faced: `sudo: error while shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

The kernel panic is a bit of a red herring here, as it's a consequence of a previous error. In your screenshot, the first abnormal boot message is:

```
/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So it looks like the file `libselinux.so.1` is now missing.

According to [Ubuntu package search engine](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libselinux.so.1),`libselinux.so.1` is in package `libselinux1` and the file should be located at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1`.

(The `Hardware name:` line in your screenshot and the presence of `do_syscall_64` and Rxx register names in the call trace tell me that you are using the 64-bit x86 version of Ubuntu, so the "Architecture" of any package you'll need to download will need to be `amd64`.)

You should [download that package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libselinux1/download) to some media you can use together with the recovery boot media, perform steps 1, 2 and 3 of [the instructions you already found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910218/sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory-not-able-to-boot-ubuntu-desktop) to gain access to the root filesystem of the damaged Ubuntu installation:

```
<boot using external media>
mount /path/to/disk /mnt
mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
```

Then reinstall the package that contains the missing/damaged library to the installation that is currently mounted at `/mnt`:

```
dpkg --root=/mnt -i <path to the package>/libselinux1_3.0-1build2_amd64.deb
```

Obviously, replace `<path to the package>` to the actual path to where you have the downloaded `libselinux1_3.0-1build2_amd64.deb` file.

Then see if you can now successfully use the `mount` command of the damaged installation:

```
chroot /mnt mount -a
```

If that results in another error message about a different missing library, use the "Search the contents of packages" section of the [package search page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) to find the package containing that library, then download and reinstall it in the same way.

(If you find that a large number of libraries have been damaged, this can become rather tedious. In that case, you might consider backing up your home directory and `/mnt/etc` and reinstalling. Your home directory will now be under `/mnt/home` if you have all on a single filesystem; otherwise see `/mnt/etc/fstab` to figure out which filesystem you'll need to mount in order to gain access to your home directory.)

If the chrooted `mount -a` command is successful, you can use `chroot /mnt` to enter the chroot environment and then rebuild the initramfs of the latest kernel:

```
update-initramfs -u -k 5.13.0-30-generic
```

Comment: can you please also look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449999/how-mere-compiling-broke-the-system)?